# How do I run a loop for a period of time in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute the loop for specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945533/how-to-execute-the-loop-for-specific-time)

So, I have an infinite loop in C#, but the thing is, I want the loop to end at some point. Not based on a count or a loop interval, but based on a period of time, so once that period of time has passed, the loop ends. How do I do such a thing?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - i Missed to see that stats

Comment: @Jacob - dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 3):

Make use of Timer or Thread to do that. you can achieve the task easily.

```
System.Threading.Timer Timer;
System.DateTime StopTime;
public void Run()
{
    StopTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
    Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 5000);
}

private void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    if(System.DateTime.Now >= StopTime)
    {
            Timer.Dispose();
            return;
    }
    // do your work.....
}
```

check other solution : [.NET, event every minute (on the minute). Is a timer the best option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329900/net-event-every-minute-on-the-minute-is-a-timer-the-best-option)

or
**Edit**

try

```
          DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);

            for (; ; )
            {
                if (dt < DateTime.Now)
                    break;
            }
```