# Implementing a loop using a timer in C#

Tags: c#, loops, timer, countdowntimer

I wanted to replace a counter based while loop with the timer based while loop in C#.

Example :

```
while(count < 100000)
{
   //do something 
}
```

to

```
while(timer < X seconds)
{
    //do something 
}
```

I have two types of timers in C# .NET for this `System.Timers` and `Threading.Timers` .
Which one will be better to use and how.I don't want to add extra time consumption or threading issues with the timer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute the loop for specific time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945533/how-to-execute-the-loop-for-specific-time)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a construct like this:

```
Timer r = new System.Timers.Timer(timeout_in_ms);
r.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
r.Enabled = true;
running = true;
while (running) {
   // do stuff
}
r.Enabled = false;

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   running = false;
}
```

Be careful though to do this on the UI thread, as it will block input.

Comment: it has to be used in a console app.Will this be a problem !

Comment: @Raulp I don't think so. Try it and find out :).

Answer (score 32):

What about using the Stopwatch class.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
//...
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
while(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < Xseconds)
{
    // do something
}
timer.Stop();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class instead of them, like;

> Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to
>   accurately measure elapsed time.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

while (sw.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(X seconds)) 
{
   //do something
}
```

From [`TimeSpan.FromSecond`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx)

> Returns a TimeSpan that represents a specified number of seconds,
>   where the specification is accurate to the nearest millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

You might as well use the `DateTime.Now.Ticks` counter:

```
long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
do
{
  //
}
while (DateTime.Now.Ticks - start < duration);
```

However, this seems to be something like busy waiting. That means that the loop will cause one core of your CPU to run at 100%. It will slow down other processes, speed up fans a.s.o. Although it depends on what you intend to do I would recommend to include `Thread.Sleep(1)` in the loop.

Comment: Wow great solution. Actually I was trying to solve the cpu issue which you perfectly described in here. Thanks a lot, I was fascinated. Regards