# Python run a function every 5 second using information from previous try

Tags: python, function, timer, parameters

I want to run a function every 5 seconds.
This code would work:

```
import threading
def notify():
    threading.Timer(5.0, notify).start()

notify()
```

What if the function need parameter from the previous run ?
I tried this:

```
import threading
def notify(since):
    threading.Timer(5.0, notify(since)).start()
# initial_id is just an integer, eg 423455677
notify(initial_id)
```

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/paulyu/anaconda/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 911, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/Users/paulyu/anaconda/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1177, in run
self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: notify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'since'
```

Howe to fix it ?
Your advice is much appreciated.
Thanks
Paul

Comment: Your input and error don't correlate. What is since supposed to be?

Comment: It's just a number I got for  the notify function. For the first run, I put a number as parameter to the notify() , which the number is retrieved by other function.

Comment: Your second example shows you called notify with no *since* parameter, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah, I actually put the initial id in the function to run.
i.e notify(initial_id) where initial_id = 423455677

Comment: Your code would recurse infinitely if you called it as per your second example. What information are you using from a previous try?

Comment: Yes, I would like to make it continuous loop, run the notify function every 5 second. Would it be better to do it with a while loop ? so that I can easily initialize the routine before the while loop start. How to control the while loop every 5 second ?

Comment: I got the answer from :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945533/how-to-execute-the-loop-for-specific-time
Will try it first. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to remember some kind of state, you generally want a class.

```
import threading

class Notifier:

    def __init__(self, since):
        self.since = since

    def notify(self):
        print(self.since)
        self.since += 1
        threading.Timer(2.0, self.notify).start()

Notifier(123).notify()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @Bono is that better? There's not much to explain.

Comment: @Alex Thanks! I created the class and tested it. Working very well. It's the first time I'm using a class. Start understand when and why to use it. :)