# Simulate Typing by Holding Thread

Tags: c#, performance

I am writing a bot with a component that simulates typing by notifying the user "Bot is typing...". To do this the service provider that hosts the bot has to be notified every 10 seconds that the bot is still working.

The number of seconds the bot is "typing" is simply determined by the length of the string divided by an arbitrary value of "characters per second".

```cs
var text = "This is my response!";
var alertServiceInSeconds = 10;
var delay = text.Length / (double) charactersPerSecond;
```

So two tasks have to be performed: sleeping the thread for the duration of `delay` while calling a method every `alertServiceInSeconds`.

I've attempted a couple of methods, but the bot seems to reply in `delay + alertServiceInSeconds` seconds, rather than just `delay` seconds. I must be missing something in this grade school math.

#### while Stopwatch.Elapsed

From: [How to execute the loop for specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945533/how-to-execute-the-loop-for-specific-time)

I feel like this method should hurt my soul because of the number of times `Math.Abs` is called. Furthermore, TriggerTyping is being called more frequently than `alertServiceInSeconds`.

```cs
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
while (stopwatch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay))
{
    if (Math.Abs((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 1000) / alertServiceInSeconds % 1) == 0)
        await client.TriggerTyping();
}
stopwatch.Stop();

await client.SendMessage(text);
```

### Thread.Sleep

This seems to get the job done, but not accurately as previously noted.

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < delay; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    if (Math.Abs(i / alertServiceInSeconds % 1) == 0)
        await client.TriggerTyping();
}

await client.SendMessage(text);
```

Questions:

1. How does this cause the bot to "type" in `delay + alertServiceInSeconds` seconds?
2. Are the tactics of these approaches okay? A sleeping for loop and a while loop dependent on TimeSpan both seem flawed but I cannot ponder a better approach.

Comment: seems you really want a timer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers

Comment: also, your %1 will always be 0, so not sure what that is all about

Comment: @KeithNicholas I've ultimately used your suggestion and read all about this. I'm not sure how I hadn't stumbled across Timers, but alas here I am. I would answer this question with your comment if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alertServiceInSeconds % 1, you need alertServiceInSeconds % 10.

You may also benefit from a task scheduling library and perhaps a queue.